# JSON serializer with json4s on phantom-dsl Collection column

Tags: json, serialization, cassandra, json4s, phantom-dsl

Have been following the collection [column tutorial for phantom-dsl](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki/Collection-columns) which requires json serializer.

The implementation below is getting the following error output;

> found   : org.dyne.danielsan.superchain.data.models.JsonVin
>
> [error]  required: org.json4s.JValue
>
> [error]     (which expands to)  org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
>
> [error]       compact(render(obj))

Any help in pointing out where I am going wrong, much appreciated. The issue is that AFAIK phantom-dsl requires the custom type to be defined, but json4s is expecting a JValue...

```
import com.websudos.phantom.CassandraTable
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._
import org.json4s.{NoTypeHints, _}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

case class Transaction(blockhash: String,
                       blocktime: Long,
                       confirmations: Int,
                       vout: List[Vout],
                       vin: List[Vin])

case class JsonVout(value: String,
                    n: String,
                    scriptPubKey: String)

case class JsonVin(coinbase: String,
                   sequence: String)

sealed class TransactionColumnFamily extends CassandraTable[TransactionColumnFamily, Transaction] {

  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

  override def fromRow(row: Row): Transaction = {
    Transaction(
      blockhash(row),
      blocktime(row),
      confirmations(row),
      vout(row),
      vin(row)
    )
  }

  object blockhash extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey[String]

  object blocktime extends LongColumn(this) with ClusteringOrder[Long] with Descending

  object confirmations extends IntColumn(this) with ClusteringOrder[Int] with Descending

  object vout extends JsonListColumn[TransactionColumnFamily, Transaction, Vout](this) {
    override def fromJson(obj: String): Vout = {
      parse(obj).extract[Vout]
    }

//This is where the first error arises

    override def toJson(obj: Vout): String = {
      compact(render(obj))
    }
  }

  object vin extends JsonListColumn[TransactionColumnFamily, Transaction, Vin](this) {
    override def fromJson(obj: String): Vin = {
      parse(obj).extract[Vin]
    }

//This is where the second error arises

    override def toJson(obj: JsonVin): String = {
      compact(render(obj))
    }
  }

}   

object TransactionColumnFamily extends TransactionColumnFamily with RootConnector {
  // some more stuff
  // some more stuff

}
```

**Correction**:

Thanks Flavian for the comment. You are correct. In the end this is what was needed for working with Json4s:

```
  object vout extends JsonListColumn[TransactionColumnFamily, Transaction, Vout](this) {
    override def fromJson(obj: String): Vout = {
      parse(obj).extract[Vout]
    }

    override def toJson(obj: Vout): String = {
      write(obj)
    }
   }

  object vin extends JsonListColumn[TransactionColumnFamily, Transaction, Vin](this) {
    override def fromJson(obj: String): Vin = {
      parse(obj).extract[Vin]
    }

    override def toJson(obj: Vin): String = {
      write(obj)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the `compact(render(obj))` calls are not working as expected. The phantom examples are based on the `lift-json` library where that exact method call produces a string.

Most likely, your `render()` method expects a `JValue`, so what you need to do is to produce a `JValue` from a `JsonVin` before calling `compact(render())`. You might get away with importing `import org.json4s.JsonDSL._`, where there should be a `render` method for different kinds of objects.

Additionally, when working with the Jackson serializer, it seems you may need to provide custom serializers, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992472/how-to-serialize-object-to-ast-using-json4s). If you can, just use the native one which doesn't need the extra steps.