# Reverse operation of extract (json4s)

Tags: scala, json4s

json4s allows user to convert a JsonAST object to a case class using `extract`.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

case class Item(name: String, price: Double)
val json = parse("""{"name": "phone", "price": 1000.0}""") // JObject(List((name,JString(phone)), (price,JDouble(1000.0))))
val item = json.extract[Item] // Item(phone,1000.0)
```

However, to convert a case class into a JsonAST object, the only way I can think of is:

1. serialize a case class using `write`
2. deserialize a string using `extract`

Like below:

```
parse(write(item)) // JObject(List((name,JString(phone)), (price,JDouble(1000.0))))
```

Is there any better way for the conversion? Thank you!

Comment: Does this cover what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992472/how-to-serialize-object-to-ast-using-json4s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Extraction.decompose` converts a case class object into a JsonAST.

```
Extraction.decompose(item) // JObject(List((name,JString(phone)), (price,JDouble(1000.0))))
```

Comment: Please add a supporting description to explain *why* this answers the question.